# Why doesn't a 4K TV give 4K resolution?

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, tv

I have designed the front page for a website that contains a lot of information. I have fixed the size of the page to 3530x2070 which should easily fit on a 4K screen with a resolution of 3840x2160.

```
<div id="mainDiv" style="width:3530px;height:2070px;border:1px black solid;">
```

However, when I connect to a 4K TV (not a monitor) I only see about 2700 pixels of width - and that's using the 4096x2160 screen resolution - the 3840x2160 is even narrower.

```
<div id="mainDiv" style="width:2700px;height:1070px;border:1px black solid;">
```

I've tried both Sony and Samsung TV models.

**Note too that the TVs each detected the proper resolution**, i.e. when I set the computer resolution for the TV to 3840 the TV says it's at 3840 and when I set the computer to 4096 the TV also shows it is set to 4096.

This means the computer and the TV agree on the resolution but the browser is not showing the full width of the webpage.

One more piece of the puzzle, on my 1920x1080 computer monitor the webpage sizing works as I expect (when I size it down to match that resolution). I lose a few pixels for borders and the browser frame and what not but that's to be expected. Losing more than 1000 pixels on the width is not what I expect.

```
<div id="mainDiv" style="width:1900px;height:1065px;border:1px black solid;">
```

I'm running off of the mini display port through an HDMI cable and as I said, both devices agree on the resolution of that connection.

Comment: I'd probably check this against how g+ renders. They're one of the few pages that scales well to 4k, presumably after Linus Torvalds yelled at them. Might be a css or other design issue, so I suspect asking a question on that aspect on another site might be useful

Comment: A 4k TV does indeed give a 4K resolution.  If your site is not being displayed at the correct resolution I can only assume its something to do with the code.

Comment: @Ramhound, I've updated the question to show the 'code'.  It's pretty straight forward.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, what is g+?

Comment: plus.google.com ?

Comment: What browser are you using? Some browsers do their own DPI scaling. In Firefox, this is controlled by `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` (open `about:config` to edit this value); -1.0 means to use the default scaling; set to 1.0 to force 1:1 scaling. Also, it is very likely that Windows is doing its own DPI scaling; you can disable that in your system's display resolution settings.

Comment: @bwDraco, I was using Chrome but did try Firefox on my monitor to verify the 1920x1080 settings.  Thanks for the info - I will try those this evening.

Comment: [`w3.org`](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html) info on the `px`, which is the [`visual angle unit`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#visual-angle-unit) of measurement for CSS. What's the physical dimensions of the TV and the DPI?

Comment: @txtechhelp, I tried on 40", 43" and 65".  I don't know the DPI of the various TVs.  It probably does have something to do with using the pixel measurement unit.  I naively assumed a pixel meant a pixel of resolution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### DPI scaling appears to be the culprit.

- Newer versions of Windows (since 8.1) automatically scale DPI for each display to adapt to displays with very high pixel density. It appears that Windows has scaled the 4K TV to 150% of normal (150% of 2700 is 4050, which is very close to 4096).
- Recent versions of Firefox and Chrome detect the system DPI scaling setting and adapt accordingly. You can disable this with certain advanced settings:

  - In Firefox, this is controlled by the `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` configuration value, which can be edited in `about:config`. `-1.0` is the default, where the browser will match the system's DPI scaling value on the primary monitor. To force Firefox to not scale DPI, set this value to `1.0`. Setting this to any other positive value instructs the browser to scale by that much (the default on your system appears to be `1.5`).
  - In Chrome, [this is controlled by the DWORD registry value `high-dpi-support` in key `HKCU\Software\Google\Chrome\Profile`](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/U_K1NHuMLic). Set to 0 to disable scaling, 1 to enable scaling, or 2 to use the default.